# Why doesn't Cabal ask me any questions after cabal init

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I've looked at cabal tutorials they always say that cabal, after `cabal init` proceeds to ask you a 'bunch of questions' (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7R-2vtPLDM) and when I run the command cabal does not do this, instead guessing everything. This happens whether I use cygwin or cmd on Windows 10.

Console output is as follows:

```
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 20 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.

Guessing dependencies...

Generating LICENSE...
Warning: unknown license type, you must put a copy in LICENSE yourself.
Generating Setup.hs...
Generating CHANGELOG.md...
Generating Main.hs...
Generating g.cabal...

Warning: no synopsis given. You should edit the .cabal file and add one.
You may want to edit the .cabal file and add a Description field.
```

(Yes, questions are the same regardless of whether or not the package list is updated)

How do I get cabal to ask me questions like normal? Do I need to reinstall? It also cannot recognise `cabal sandbox init` as a command, but that's another question.

Comment: It seems that in recent versions of cabal-install, one has to invoke `cabal init --interactive` and answer "no" tho the "generate a simple project with sensible defaults" question. Also, sandboxes are now obsolete; within a cabal project, `cabal build` should install any required dependencies and build the local package, without having to create a sandbox.

Comment: Thanks, it asks the questions now. @danidiaz do you know if this is related to the sandbox issue?

Comment: It's unrelated to the sandbox issue. You can recover the old sandox command with the prefix `v1-`, like `cabal v1-sandbox`. That said, the new way of handling installed dependencies (called "nix-style" in the manual) https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build-overview.html is strictly better than sandboxes, and should be preferred whenever possible.

Comment: @danidiaz you should post your first comment as an answer, since it fully satisfies the question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in recent versions of cabal-install, one has to `invoke cabal init --interactive` and answer "no" tho the "generate a simple project with sensible defaults" question.

Also, sandboxes are now obsolete; within a cabal project, `cabal build` should install any required dependencies and build the local package, without having to create a sandbox.

The new way of handling installed dependencies (called ["nix-style"](http://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build-overview.html) in the manual) is strictly better than sandboxes. It avoids cabal dependency hell—like sandboxes did—and also avoids having to build the same dependency multiple times, because compiled dependencies are saved in a central store and can be reused across projects.